# Coq: matching inside Inductive definition

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

I'd like to implement in Coq something like the following code:

```
Inductive IT :=
| c1 : IT
| c2 (x:IT) (H:
 match x as x return Prop with 
 | c1 => True
 | c2 y => False
 end): IT.
```

But it is not possible to match undefined type.
How to overcome this obstacle?

(I need to check some property of term before using it.
For example, the aim - to check the correctness of subformula before constructing larger formula.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want what is known as an [inductive-recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction-recursion).  Coq unfortunately does not support this feature, although other proof assistants such as Agda and Idris do.

The best way of avoiding induction-recursion for your type is probably to define a raw inductive type without the constraints, and define a separate predicate that carves out well-formed elements:

```
Inductive preIT :=
| c1 : preIT
| c2 : preIT -> preIT.

Definition wfIT (x : preIT) :=
  match x with
  | c1        => true
  | c2 c1     => true
  | c2 (c2 _) => false
  end.

Record IT := {
  it_val : preIT;
  _      : wfIT it_val
}.
```

The [Mathematical Components](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/ssreflect-1.5/Ssreflect.eqtype.html#) library has good support for this programming pattern; look for the `subType` class in the above link.